# SQL - Unique key instead of primary key

Tags: sql-server

I have unique contraint on 5 nullable columns that represent identifier of one row.
Is it okay to create unique key and create clustered index on it instead of primary key? I cannot use primary key on these columns because they are nullable, and i cannot create identity column because there are lot of deletes and inserts and it will make overflow on this identity column.

Comment: Yes? No? What? Please create a [mcve]. What is the intended purpose? You gotta give us something to work with.

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product (and different products behave differently with NULL values and unique constraints) Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using `postgresql`, `oracle`, `sql-server`, `db2`, ...

Comment: I would not even recommend creating a key over 5 columns. Why not use an ID column?

Comment: Why don't you want to use a primary key?

Comment: Its in sqlserver. This table should be deleted and be insereted many times so the id grow until infinite theoratically. So i wanted to prevent the use of limited identity column

Comment: But you can set all the fields together as a compound primary key...you don't have to have a separate ID column if that's not appropriate

Comment: The columns are nullable so cannot be part of primary key

Comment: `there are lot of deletes and inserts and it will make overflow on this identity column.`  - the identity column can be `bigint` or even `decimal(38,0)` so that isn't a good reason. Do you have any non clustered indexes on this table? What kind of queries will you be doing against this table? Will they benefit from this index?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, and there's an argument that this is actually "better" than a primary key, as the rule that a primary key column is non nullable is in many ways an artificial constraint.

If you make it a `UNIQUE CLUSTERED INDEX` then you get just about everything that a primary key brings to the table except the unwanted rule that the columns must be non nullable.  However, they must still be unique, so you could only ever have one row where all five columns in your index are null for example.

So you can use your index when creating foreign key constraints, you will guarantee the order data is stored, and each row must be unique.  However, the index probably won't be incredibly useful for querying, and, because it's going to be wide, and you said there's a lot of deletes/ inserts, it will have a tendency to fragment your data.

Personally, I would be tempted to make it a unique constraint, but not clustered.  Then it will do the job of keeping non-unique data from being created.

You could then add a surrogate key and make this the primary key.  I doubt you would ever "run out" (or "overflow"?) of numbers doing this.

---

So why would I use a surrogate key?

Your surrogate key will be much narrower, so less impact from fragmentation due to so many inserts/ updates/ deletes.

It's then useful if you need to extend your database.  Say you only have one table, and this is always going to be the only table in the entire database.  In this one scenario it would make sense to not bother with a surrogate key.  It doesn't give you any value; it's just an unnecessary overhead.

However, let's assume that you have other tables hanging off your "main" table (the one with 5 columns forming a unique key).  Adding a surrogate key here allows you to make any child tables with a single id that links back to the parent table.  The alternative would be to enforce the addition of ALL five columns forming the unique (candidate) key every time you create a child table.

Now you have a narrow clustered index that actually serves a purpose, and the fragmentation will not be quite as bad as it would with five columns.

Comment: What is the advantage then, to add surrogate key ?

Comment: What about the case of no other table will reference to this table and every 30 minutes all data in the table is deleted and insert new data ?

Comment: So why are you enforcing uniqueness?  Surely it would be easier to handle this in the data population step?  If you have no other way to do this then sure, create a `UNIQUE INDEX` on your table (I wouldn't bother making it `CLUSTERED`) and live with the fact that if there's duplicates in your source data that your population step will fail.

Comment: I am enforcing uniqueness to prevent insert 2 same data rows. Should i add unique contraint + unique index? Or just one of them is enough?

Comment: One unique constraint on the five columns should suffice (constraint = index in your sentence - they are the same thing in this context).  My point is that, if you can spot 2 duplicate rows in your data BEFORE you attempt to load it into your table than that's probably more efficient that trying to bash it in, then it failing because it finds a duplicate.

Comment: In the case i cant detect duplicates before the insert. Should i use unique key and/or unique index?

Comment: And why is it nonclustered index?

Comment: What will make faster read of all the rows?             1. Surrogate key + clustered index.                   2. Composite key + clustered index.                     3. Composite key + nonclustered index ?

Comment: Composite key, non-clustered unique index if you literally just want to push data into a table, deal with duplicates (it will prevent this during the insert), and then read the data back in no particular order.

Comment: Let's be very clear here, I am talking about `CREATE UNIQUE INDEX <index_name> ON <table_name> (<5 columns that make up the key>);`